# update records through a @future callout method inside a before/after update trigger fires

Tags: callout, future

I have a trigger that fires when the address has changed on a record. 
I make a callout to Google API to gain the longitude and latitude information that I then want to put inside of my record. 
When I use database.update(sObject), I get an error that I cannot update inside of an update trigger so I would like to find a work-around for this.
This is the function that will perform the callout:

```
 @future(callout=true) public static void updateGeoLocation( Set<Id> objectsToUpdate, String objectAPI_Name, String longitudeAPI_Name, String latitudeAPI_Name, String streetAPI_Name, String cityAPI_Name, String countryAPI_Name, String zipAPI_Name )
{
    System.debug( 'get here?' );
    String placeHolder      = 'SELECT Id, {0}, {1}, {2}, {3}, {4}, {5} FROM {6}'; 
    List<String> fillers    = new List<String>{ longitudeAPI_Name, latitudeAPI_Name, streetAPI_Name, cityAPI_Name, countryAPI_Name, zipAPI_Name, objectAPI_Name };
    String soqlQuery        = String.format( placeHolder, fillers );

    soqlQuery               += ' WHERE Id IN : ' + 'objectsToUpdate';
    List<sObject> sobjList  = Database.query( soqlQuery );

    System.Debug( 'number of thingies: ' + sobjList );

    for ( sObject sObj : sobjList )
    {
        String street   = ( String )sObj.get( streetAPI_Name );
        String city     = ( String )sObj.get( cityAPI_Name );
        String country  = ( String )sObj.get( countryAPI_Name );
        String zip      = ( String )sObj.get( zipAPI_Name );

        String url              = 'https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=' + sanitizeLocation( street, city, country, zip ) + '&key=' + Label.GeoApiKeyMassUpdate;
        googleMapsResponse res  = requestGeoLocation( url );

        googleMapsResponse.location loc = res.results[0].geometry.location;

        sObj.put( longitudeAPI_Name, loc.lng );
        sObj.put( latitudeAPI_Name, loc.lat );
    }
    update sobjList;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you calling this in a before update trigger? Because it's not allowed to update the records being processed by the trigger by using a DML operation. Not sure if `@future` has any impact on this.

If you are doing it before update, try directly modifying the fields of the objects in `Trigger.new`, otherwise call this function only *after* update.

Comment: thank you for your reply,
I tried it both in before and after and got the same error.
Since a callout through a trigger can only be made in a @future function and a future function does not allow to pass a list of objects and must be of type void, I'm afraid I also can't change the data directly in the Trigger.new.

Comment: What's the error you're getting exactly?

Comment: The error message that I get is: Future method cannot be called from a future or batch method: CalculateGeoLocationAndUpdateRecord.updateGeoLocation(Set<Id>, String, String, String, String, String, String, String)

So my first guess is that update itself is a future method

Comment: @JurVanOerle It sounds like your first geolocation update starts another update trigger invocation that then tries to call the future method again. If this is the case, you should find a way to identify that these objects already have the right information and avoid calling the future method in that case.

Comment: I did this:  http://pastebin.com/PyGGfYuf

Comment: @JurVanOerle The function is still being called every time, even is the list of Ids is empty. Try wrapping the call in `if(idsToGeoLocate.size() > 0){ ... }` to catch this.

Comment: o wow, what a rooky mistake :( I have spent several hours on this already. 
It is working now!
Thank you ever so much! :D